# VB.net how to encrypt with private key using RSA

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, rsa

I keep trying to encrypt using my private RSA key, and decrypting with my public RSA key, but I can't decrypt without getting *"Decrypt(): Key not valid for use in specified state."*

**Oh, and I realize that you usually encrypt with the public key - that's not what I'm trying to do. Please don't spam the thread with "learn how PKE works"**

What I need this for is to be able to encrypt patches (about 200 bytes of base 64 text) on my computer, then have the program decrypt with the public key, proving I made the patch.
Can I get some help, or do you know of any libraries that would make this easier?

Decrypt function:

```
    Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal Data() As Byte, ByVal Privatekey As String) As RSAResult
    Try
        Dim RSA As System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider = New System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider()
        RSA.FromXmlString(Privatekey)
        Dim Result As New RSAResult(RSADecrypt(Data, RSA.ExportParameters(True), False))
        Return Result
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Decrypt(): " & ex.Message, ex)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Your use case call for a cryptographic [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) algorithm instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RRSAParameters structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [RSACryptoServiceProvider's ImportParamaters method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This lets you create your own keys for encrypting with RSA.

For a definition of D, Dp, Dq, Exponent, InverseQ, Modulus, P, and Q, I suggest checking out the Wikipedia page on RSA for Cryptography. This covers how to generate a key, as well as what each parameter is for. Towards the bottom there is even a representation of the algorithm.